# Python filter records from csv looking-up another csv

Tags: python, csv, filter, compare

I am trying to create a csv file, let's call it File-C, by looking up some 'IDs' from File-A in File-B.

```
If File-B has the 'ID' from File-A 
      THEN put the record in File-C.
```

The look-up file has below csv format:

```
File-A
ID,incr,event
1111.1234557,5,missing create
```

The data file has the 'ID' attribute and other attributes:

```
File-B
ID,incr,name,email,accountno
1111.1234557,5,john,emailaddress,22020233902
```

The output or File-C will be exactly like data file but with less records since they got filtered based on what we found in the look-up file.

I have written the below code and it gives the error 'index out of range'. I have a feeling it has to do with the size of two lists being looped through. I don't know how are they connected.

```
def read_from_file(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file, 'rt') as f:
        file_reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(file_reader, None)
        data = list(file_reader)
    return data


data_file= read_from_file('/CSV_RECORDS_20200308_A.csv')
lookup_file= read_from_file('/CSV_RECORDS_20200308_B.csv')

output_data = []

for row in lookup_file:
    for val in data_file:
        if row[0] == val[0]: ## FAILES HERE WITH ERROR 'IndexError: list index out of range'##
            output_data.append(row)


with open('/INSERTBACK_TEST.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(output_data)
```

Full error message is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

runtime_1   |   File "/opt/project/etl/landing/unibanks/code.py", line 102, in

runtime_1   |     if row[0] == val[0]:

runtime_1   | IndexError: list index out of range

I can't seem to figure this out. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The CSV looks odd, is that a problem with the formatting here on Stack Overflow? **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Comment: yeah I just added spaces for readability. I'll remove them.

Comment: full error message is Traceback (most recent call last):
runtime_1   |   File "/opt/project/etl/landing/unibanks/replica-dentist-recon.py", line 102, in <module>
runtime_1   |     if row[0] == val[0]:
runtime_1   | IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That kind of information should go in your post, it's painful to read as a comment.

Comment: updated the post with full error message.

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Yes. Python and Pycharm are quite new to me. Need to get a better understanding of iterables. I do spend time on problem before posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you have some empty list read from one of the files.

```
val = []
print(val[0])
>>out
>>list index out of range
```

Check you're files for empty lines.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had 1 empty line at the end of the look-up file.